# Hide 'Add' option from widget="many2many" kanban in odoo 14

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, kanban, odoo-14

How can i hide 'Add' option from many2many field kanban widget mode.i tried with options="{'no_create': True}" but its not working

```
<field name="members" widget="many2many_kanban" options="{'no_create': True}"
                                   context="{'form_view_ref': 'project_team.project_team_form_view', 'default_type_team':'project'}"
                                   attrs="{'readonly':['|',('state','not in',['open']),('project_m_user','!=',True)]}">
                                <kanban quick_create="false" create="true" delete="true">
                                    <field name="id"/>
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <templates>
                                        <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                            <div class="oe_kanban_global_click" style="max-width: 200px">
                                                <div class="o_kanban_record_top">
                                                    <img t-att-src="kanban_image('res.users', 'image_small', record.id.raw_value)"
                                                         height="40" width="40"
                                                         class="oe_avatar oe_kanban_avatar_smallbox mb0"/>
                                                    <div class="o_kanban_record_headings ml8">
                                                        <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                                            <field name="name"/>
                                                        </strong>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--<a t-if="! read_only_mode" type="delete"
                                                       class="text-danger">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </a>-->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </t>
                                    </templates>
                                </kanban>
                            </field>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can `options` attribute of the field tag.

In your case, you need to use "no_create" and if you don't allow edit, use "no_create_edit"

For example:

> <field name="many2many_field_name" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create': True}"

**EDIT:**

> <field name="members" mode="kanban" widget="many2many" options="{'no_create': True}"

Comment: both are tried but this options not worked.

Answer (score 0):

change `create="true"` to `create="false"`
it worked for me in the tree view